# The equivalent definition of Nowhere dense set

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

$X$ is a metric space, $E \subset X$.

Prove that

a) $ {(\bar E) ^{\circ}} = \varnothing$ (the interior of closure of E
is empty)

$$ \Leftrightarrow $$

b) Given any non-empty open ball $U$
there is a non-empty open ball $V \subset U$
such that $E \cap V=\varnothing $.

I have proven that a) $\Rightarrow$ b) by proving $\bar E \cap V=\varnothing $, but for b) $\Rightarrow$ a) I can only get $E^{\circ} =\varnothing $ instead of ${(\bar E)^{\circ}}= \varnothing$.

Thanks a lot if you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $(b)\implies (a)$: Suppose on the contrary that $(\bar E)^o\ne \emptyset$. Take any $x\in (\bar E)^o$. There exists an open ball $U_x$ centered at $x$ that lies in $\bar E$, i.e., $x\in U_x\subset \bar E$. By $(b)$, there exists a **non empty** ball $V_x\subset U_x$ such that $V_x\cap E=\emptyset$.

Note that $V_x$ being a non empty subset of $\bar E$ contains a limit point of $E$ so $V_x\cap E\ne \emptyset$, which contradicts what was obtained in the last para.

So $(\bar E)^o=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 3):

$E \cap U=\emptyset$ implies $E \subseteq X\setminus U$. Since $X\setminus U$ is a closed set we get $\overline E \subseteq X\setminus U$ or $\overline E \cap U=\emptyset$. Can you finish?

Comment: If $E \subset X \setminus U$ then $\overline E \subseteq \overline {X\setminus U} $, right? Since $X\setminus U$ is close then according to definition of closed set we get $X\setminus U =\overline {X\setminus U}$,so any open ball $U$ is not a subset of $\overline E$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. @anyon

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bonus exercise.

Call a set $F$ *hollow* if it has an empty interior. Call $F$ *nowhere dense* if the closure of $F$ is hollow.

1. Show that a set is hollow if and only if its complement is dense.
2. Show a set is nowhere dense if and only if the interior of its complement is dense.

Demonstrate these in any topological space.

Hints: (2) follows from (1). (1) follows since an open $U$ with $U\cap(X\setminus F)=\emptyset$ is the same thing as a closed container of $X\setminus F$. What can we say about closed sets containing $X\setminus F$?